# trying to add Nan un-ordered list to my php code

Tags: php, html

i am trying to add an UN-ordered list in a PHP code

```
<?php

echo "list of cities in kenya"

echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>Nairobi</li>" ;
    echo "<li>kisumu</li>";
    echo "<li>Mombasa</li>";
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

this is what i was expecting

```
list of cities in kenya 

  - Nairobi
  - Kisumu
  - Mombasa
```

Comment: The only thing that is really missing is a semi-colon after `echo "list of cities in kenya"`. See: https://3v4l.org/78ov9 (press the little eye icon in the right upper corner of the output)

Comment: Also you don't need PHP for this at all.